# Java, XML DocumentBuilder - setting the encoding when parsing

Tags: java, xml, encoding, xml-parsing, domdocument

I'm trying to save a tree (extends `JTree`) which holds an `XML` document to a `DOM Object` having changed it's structure.

I have created a new document object, traversed the tree to retrieve the contents successfully (including the original encoding of the `XML` document), and now have a `ByteArrayInputStream` which has the tree contents (`XML` document) with the correct encoding.

The problem is when I parse the `ByteArrayInputStream` the encoding is changed to `UTF-8` (in the `XML` document) automatically.

Is there a way to prevent this and use the correct encoding as provided in the `ByteArrayInputStream`.

It's also worth adding that I have already used the
    `transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, encoding)`  method to retrieve the right encoding.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can your share a bit of your code?

Answer (score 5):

Here's an updated answer since OutputFormat is deprecated :

```
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(writer));
String output = writer.getBuffer().toString().replaceAll("\n|\r", "");
```

The second part will return the XML Document as String

Answer (score 3):

```
// Read XML
String xml = "xml"
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

// Append formatting
OutputFormat format = new OutputFormat(document);

if (document.getXmlEncoding() != null) {
  format.setEncoding(document.getXmlEncoding());
}

format.setLineWidth(100);
format.setIndenting(true);
format.setIndent(5);
Writer out = new StringWriter();
XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(out, format);
serializer.serialize(document);
String result = out.toString();
```

Comment: Some explanation of this code would be useful for those who come and read this answer later.

Comment: Also it would be useful to mention which `XMLSerializer` you use. `org.apache.xml.serialize.XMLSerializer` I assume ? - using the "internal" ones of the sun package would be really bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it, given alot of trial and errors.

I was using

```
OutputFormat format = new OutputFormat(document);
```

but changed it to

```
OutputFormat format = new OutputFormat(d, encoding, true);
```

and this solved my problem.

`encoding` is what I set it to be
`true` refers to whether or not indent is set.

Note to self - read more carefully - I had looked at the javadoc hours ago - if only I'd have read more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me and is very simple. No need for a transformer or output formatter:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource(inputStream);
is.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1"); // set your encoding here
Document document = builder.parse(is);
```