# Edit xml declaration encoding with java

Tags: java, xml, encoding, utf-8, xml-declaration

I am editing an xml-file with original encoding ASCII in the declaration. In the resulting file I want the encoding to be UTF-8 in order to write Swedish characters like åäö, something I can't do at the moment.

An example file equivalent to my file can be found at [archivematica wiki](https://wiki.archivematica.org/images/2/20/METS.752545fa-6869-41d4-95b1-710ac659525d.xml).

The resulting SIP.xml that I get after running my program with a copy of the above example file can be reached at [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tdd9p7xlkl8gwql/SIP.xml?dl=0). The added tag with the åäö text is in the very end of the document.

As seen in the code below I have tried setting the encoding on the transformer, and also tried to use an OutputStreamWriter to set the encoding.
In the end I edited the declaration in the original file to UTF-8 and finally åäö was written out. So the problem seems to be the encoding of the original file. If I'm not mistaken it shouldn't cause any problem to change the declaration from ASCII to UTF-8, the question is, how do I do this within my program? Can I do this after parsing it to a Document object, or do I need to do something before parsing?

```
package provklasser;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class Provklass {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File chosenFile = new File("myFile.xml");
            //parsing the xml file
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document metsDoc = builder.parse(chosenFile.getAbsolutePath());

            Element agent = (Element) metsDoc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(metsDoc.createElementNS("http://www.loc.gov/METS/","mets:agent"));
            agent.appendChild(metsDoc.createTextNode("åäö"));

            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(metsDoc);

            // write the content into xml file
            File newFile = new File(chosenFile.getParent(), "SIP.xml");

            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");

            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(newFile);

            //Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("SIP.xml"), "UTF-8");
            //StreamResult result = new StreamResult(out);
            transformer.transform(source, result);

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Provklass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SAXException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Provklass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Provklass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Provklass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (TransformerException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Provklass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }



}
```

UPDATE:
Using metsDoc.getInputEncoding() returns UTF-8, while metsDoc.getXmlEncoding() returns ASCII.  If I parse the new file after saving it and make a new Document I get the same result. So the document seems to have the right encoding, but the xml declaration is not right.

Now I edit the xml as a text file before parsing it, replacing the parsing part above with `parseXML(chosenFile.getAbsoutePath());` and using the following methods:

```
private String withEditedDeclaration(String fileName) {
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    try {

        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(fileName))) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            text.append(line.replaceFirst("ASCII", "UTF-8") + NL);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

                text.append(scanner.nextLine() + NL);
            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MetsAdaption.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 
    return text.toString();
}

private void parseXML(String fileName) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
    String xmlString = withEditedDeclaration(fileName);

    //parsing the xml file
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlString));
    metsDoc = builder.parse(is);
}
```

It works, but it seems like an ugly solution. I'd be most grateful if anyone knew a better way.

Comment: Maybe this could help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578395/java-xml-documentbuilder-setting-the-encoding-when-parsing

Comment: @Berger Thank you for your tip. However, I don't think this solves my problem. OutputFormat seems to be deprecated and I've already used transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, encoding). I think I need to edit the declaration of the document, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: It seems like this should work (the `DocumentBuilder` should honor the xml declaration). Which leads me to think that your document might not be OK. Could you check if your base file really is an ASCII document (not only does it say so in its XML prolog, but this is actually true if you look at the actual bytes ?).

Comment: @GPI Thank you. According to Firefox the original document is Windows-1252, so maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @GPI If I change the declaration of the original doc to Windows-1252 I still get input encoding UTF-8 (xml encoding Windows-1252) after parsing, do you know what causes that? Is DocumentBuilder's default encoding UTF-8? I can't find any information on that. Can I somehow set the encoding used by DocumentBuilder?

Comment: The easiest way for that would be to feed the `DocumentBuilder` a `java.io.Reader`, and not a file path as you currently do. e.g. `parse(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), yourEncoding)`. If you could share your actual XML (dropbox link, github Gist, whatever), I maybe could have a look. Maybe you could share also what XML parser you are using (println the class name of your document builder ?).

Comment: @GPI I'm not sure I'm allowed to share my xml but the example at [archivematica wiki](https://wiki.archivematica.org/images/2/20/METS.752545fa-6869-41d4-95b1-710ac659525d.xml) should be equivalent. println of the class gives: class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl

Comment: Thanks. OK, so could you edit your question by producing a small code that exhibits your issue. Here, your code simply prints the input file as is, so there's no encoding issue. Could you please provide a sample code with this given file, and producing a bad output ?

Comment: @GPI About the Reader - there doesn't seem to be a parse method in DocumentBuilder taking a Reader.

Comment: @GPI I'm not sure I completely understand what you're asking for. I might have been unclear in my question. The last part (after "update") actually works, but does not seem like a good solution having to read the entire document as a String. The original code at the top is causing a mismatch between input encoding and xml encoding.

Comment: The mismatch in and of istelf is not an issue. getInputEncoding() returns what the parser used, and UTF-8 and ASCII are completely interchangeable over the ASCII charset, so this is not an issue. getXMLEncoding() reports what was written in the prologue, whatever that may be. So what you have actually works as far as I can tell. What I asked was if you could show an actual issue (e.g. an ouptut document that has wrongly encoded chars in swedish or other).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where my xml declaration was originally:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
```

But after parsing to a `Document` and then back to `XML` as `UTF-8` the encoding stayed as `windows-1252` even though the bytes themselves where `UTF-8`. I eventually worked out that the implementation of `TransformerFactory` was `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl` changing that to:

```
org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl
```

from Apache Xalan Java 2.7.1 resulted in the charset in the XML deceleration being correctly set and now I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```