# Error when parsing XML file in Java

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

I am trying to parse an xml file for the attributes:

Testcase: name & status

testSteps: expected, actual, & status

but I'm getting this error:

```
[Fatal Error] xmltestdata.xml:4:1635: The value of attribute "expected" associated with an element type "testSteps" must not contain the '<' character.
```

What is the reason I would be getting this error?

### Java

```
private static JiraIssue parseXML(String xmlFile) {
    try {

        //Read the XML File 
        File xmlFile1 = new File(xmlFile);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory
        DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile1);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        System.out.println("Root element :" + 
        doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());


    }

    finally {
    return null;

    }
}
```

### XML (Sorry about the poor formatting)

```html
<xml>
  <testSuite name="Suite: Test Reporter" startTime="05/22/2017 14:07:57" endTime="05/22/2017 14:07:57">

    <!-- name would have the (1) MSA ticket and (2) test status-->

    <testCase name="MSA001|en|us" status="Pass">

      <!-- below could be the (3) comment-->

      <testSteps name="Step 1" expected="Γεια σας. ξεκινήστε με τη UPS." actual="Γεια σας. ξεκινήστε με τη UPS." status="Pass" />
      <testSteps name="Step 2" expected="Αποστολή" actual="Αποστολή" status="Pass" />                     </testCase>

    <testCase name="MSA002|en|ca" status="Fail">


      <testSteps name="Step 1" expected="Bonjour. Démarrez avec UPS." actual="Bonjour. Démarrez avec UPS." status="Pass" />
      <testSteps name="Step 2" expected="Bonjour. Démarrez avec UPS." actual="Not found" status="Fail" />                     </testCase>

    <testCase name="MSA003|en|fr" status="Skip">

      <testSteps name="Step 1" expected="Dobrý den. začněte využívat služby UPS." actual="Αποστολή" status="Fail" />
      <testSteps name="Step 3" expected="Dobrý den. začněte využívat služby UPS." actual="Dobrý den. začněte využívat služby UPS." status="Pass" />                     </testCase>

    <testCase name="MSA004|en|ls" status="Fail">


      <testSteps name="Step 1" expected="Dobrý den. začněte využívat služby UPS." actual="Αποστολή" status="Fail" />
      <testSteps name="Step 2" expected="Dobrý den. začněte využívat služby UPS." actual="Dobrý den. začněte využívat služby UPS." status="Pass" />                     </testCase>

    <testCase name="MSA005|en|us" status="Fail">

      <testSteps name="Step 1" expected="<b>Γεια σας. ξεκινήστε με τη UPS.</b>" actual="Γεια σας. ξεκινήστε με τη UPS." status="Pass" />
      <testSteps name="Step 2" expected="Αποστολή" actual="Αποστολή" status="Fail" />                     </testCase>
  </testSuite>
</xml>`
```

Comment: The XML is badly formatted `<testSteps name="Step 1" expected="<b>Γεια σας. ξεκινήστε με τη UPS.</b>" actual="Γεια σας. ξεκινήστε με τη UPS." status="Pass" />` - the `<b>` and `</b>` are invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is here:

```
     <testSteps name="Step 1" expected="<b>Γεια σας. ξεκινήστε με τη UPS.</b>" actual="Γεια σας. ξεκινήστε με τη UPS." status="Pass" />
```

You cannot have `<` in attribute value; it should be replaced with `&lt;`

So correct line should be

```
<testSteps name="Step 1" expected="&lt;b>Γεια σας. ξεκινήστε με τη UPS.&lt;/b>" actual="Γεια σας. ξεκινήστε με τη UPS." status="Pass" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You may get problem about encoding. Let's try to set encoding (I don't know what is your language in this xml, please try to find your encoding and set). [A reference to set encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578395/java-xml-documentbuilder-setting-the-encoding-when-parsing)